# Expectation of a series of random variables with a random variable as upper limit

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expectation

I'm wondering what the expected value of $E[\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i]$ is, where N ~ Ge(p).

My first thought was that,

$E[\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i]$ = $E[\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)]$ = $E[\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i|N=n) (1-p)^{^{i-1}}p]$

however I am not sure if this is correct, and if it is, what $(X_i|N=n)$ is equal to.

Comment: It all depends on the dependence structure between N and the sequence (X_i).

Comment: They are independent.

Comment: See answer below. Note that "(Xi|N=n)" does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum is $$S=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i\mathbf 1_{N\geqslant i},$$ hence, if $N$ is independent of $(X_i)$, then $$E(S)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty E(X_i\mathbf 1_{N\geqslant i})=\sum_{i=1}^\infty E(X_i)P(N\geqslant i).$$ If furthermore $E(X_i)$ does not depend on $i$, then $$E(S)=E(X)\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(N\geqslant i)=E(X)E(N).$$